# Normal subgroup of a normal subgroup of a group is not always a normal subgroup of a group. Prove using GAP.

Tags: group-theory, normal-subgroups, gap

How could I show that a normal subgroup of a normal subgroup of a group is not always a normal subgroup of a group?

Here is what I did. I know the Algebra system GAP, so I wrote the following function:

```
performTheProve:= function()
    local g, gDash, AFour, NormalOfAFour, NormalK;
    AFour:=AlternatingGroup(4);
    NormalOfAFour:=NormalSubgroups(AFour);
    for g in  NormalOfAFour do
        for gDash in NormalSubgroups(g) do
            if(not gDash in NormalOfAFour) then
                return [gDash, g];
            fi;         
        od;
    od;
end;
```

This function produces the following result:

```
[ Group([ (1,2)(3,4) ]), Group([ (1,3)(2,4), (1,2)(3,4) ]) ]
```

So, now I am stating that the `Group([ (1,3)(2,4), (1,2)(3,4) ])` is a normal subgroup of a ${A}_{4}$, `Group([ (1,2)(3,4) ])` is a normal subgroup of a `Group([ (1,3)(2,4), (1,2)(3,4) ])` and not a normal subgroup of a ${A}_{4}$.

Given this example I am proving that normal subgroup of a normal subgroup of a group is not always a normal subgroup of a group. Am I right?

Comment: Yes, that's a standard example.

Comment: Just a question for my own amusement: surely if the containing group is abelian, that would be a sufficient, if not necessary condition for transitivity, wouldn't it?